# creating bar plot of grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:18),
                  Question = c('v1_item_1', 'v1_item_1', 'v2_item_1', 'v2_item_2', 'v1_item_2', 'v2_item_2','v1_item_2', 'v2_item_2','v1_item_2', 'v2_item_2','v1_item_3','v2_item_3','v1_item_3','v2_item_3','v1_item_3','v2_item_3','v1_item_4','v2_item_4'),
Answer = sample(1:5, 18, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a bar plot to show the difference between mean ratings for the two variants of the items.

I am approaching it by using group by to group the data by the question and then mutate to create a col of means:

```
df<- df %>% 
  group_by(Question)%>%
  mutate(mean = mean(Answer))
```

And then using ggplot2 to create a bar chart displaying the mean for each item:

```
ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=Question, y=mean))
```

However, I would like to cluster the bars to directly compare the means of different versions of the same item (with v1_item_1 next to v2_item_1, v1_item_2 next to v2_item_2...etc).

At the moment I am thinking that I will need to reshape my data to separate the v1 and v2 categories to do this but I was wondering if there is a quick way to do this that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to separate the `Question` variable. For this we use `separate` function with its `merge` argument to separate at the first underline:
The rest is quite obvious:
Note: `separate` is superseded. Check `?separate()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate(Question, into = c("Version", "Item"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE, 
           extra = "merge") %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Answer, na.rm = TRUE), .by= c(Item, Version)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Item, y = Mean, fill = Version)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Item", y = "Mean Rating", fill = "Version")
```

[image]